# Python Regex search not showing month text

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to validate the String against RegEx pattern and then I want month and Year from pattern search. The pattern match is good, I can see date and year but month is empty

```
import re

txt = '25-Nov-18'
pattern = re.compile('^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)[a-zA-Z]{3}(\/|-)(\d{2})$')
if pattern.match(txt):
    m = pattern.search(txt)
    print(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4))
```

Result is

```
25 - - 18
```

FYI: m.group(0) is `25-Nov-18`

Am I missing anything here?
Is there any better way than this?

Comment: No, you are not missing anything, you just printed what you captured. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WR0zhK/1). You must have wanted `'^(\d{1,2})[/-]([a-zA-Z]{3})[/-](\d{2})$'` and print 3 groups. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/WR0zhK/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing some parenthesis and another group, you have to surround in parenthesis everything you want to recover.

```
import re

txt = '25-Nov-18'
pattern = re.compile('^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)([a-zA-Z]{3})(\/|-)(\d{2})$')
if pattern.match(txt):
    m = pattern.search(txt)
    print(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4), m.group(5))
```